# Wandering focus between shots 5D Mark iv

Tags: autofocus, camera, focus-motor, canon-5d-mark-iv

I've been using my Canon 5D Mark iv in a professional capacity for almost five years, and a few months ago I started to feel like it wasn't sharp. Of course at first I thought this would be a lens issue, so I calibrated and serviced all my lenses as well as camera bodies.

Fast-forward to a shoot last weekend where I realised something MUST be off. Three photos taken from the same position, and only one of them would be anywhere near in focus. This is using manual mode with centre focus selected.

I tested the 5D mark iv and 24-70 mm f/2.8 on a calibration tool today and found that the focus 'wanders' between identical setups i.e tripod, shooting tethered, taking the photos in sequence without taking my eye from the viewfinder between shots to keep the centre focus on the centre square of the lens calibration tool.

Has anyone experienced anything like this? If so, any idea on what the fix/repair might be?

Images attached, note the '0' and '6' between shots:
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: What AF Mode are you using (One Shot AF/AI Servo AF)? What AF point/area selection (Spot, Single, Expanded+4, Expanded+8, Area, Large Area, etc.? How much light are you shooting in? (ISO? Tv? Av?) When you say "Manual mode" are you talking about Manual Exposure or Manual AF?

Comment: Why is your target not centered properly and not sitting square to your camera? If you're testing with the center AF point, the middle of the frame should be directly over the intersection of the four largest squares (upper right an lower left are black, upper left and lower right are white). Both sides of the target (*NOT* including the slanted ruler) should be the same distance from the center of your lens. It's pretty obvious in your sample images that the right side is closer than the left side to the camera, as the camera if far enough to the right to see the right side of the back.

Comment: @MichaelC, technically datacolor recommends focusing on the smaller concentric squares nearest the scale using the center focus point. Either way, it's not set up right nor square to the camera...

Comment: I would take multiple images all starting with the focus set to MFD, and then several starting with the focus set to infinity... that will tell you if there is excessive gear lash in the focus drive (or perhaps drag, depending on type of drive motor). There is a tolerance for AF, so some variability is to be expected. Combine that with improper setup, and possibly handholding (?), these results are not that surprising IMO.

Comment: @StevenKersting Yes, Datacolor recommends that, but many cameras have AF "points" with areas of sensitivity large enough that if one points the indicator in the VF over the middle of that smaller target part of the area of sensitivity will be over the ruler, parts of which are closer/further than the target. If the contrast of the ruler is stronger than the contrast of the target (which shouldn't happen, but poor lighting conditions can play a lot of tricks on AF performance) then the camera will attempt to focus on the highest contrast in the active AF area(s).

Comment: That's just one of the reasons I preferred the LensAlign Pro over the LensCal system. LensAlign had two small holes in the flat target with two red dots directly behind them on a second plate. When both dots were visible  from the camera it meant the target was properly aligned with the camera's sensor instead of tilted, as can be seen rather obviously in the example images above. But in my experience, even LensCal seems to give more consistent results when aiming at the center of the larger squares than when using the smaller on directly next to the ruler. YMMV.

Comment: The other issue with the test setup is that the target is supposed to be about 30X-50X focal length for testing. That would make the target much larger in the field of view. At 24mm the target would be just over two feet (30X) to just under four feet (50X) away from the focal plane mark on the top of the camera. At 70mm it should only be just under seven feet (30X) to eleven feet (50X) from the same mark. (100mm= 0.328 feet)